# Prioritize overlapping date ranges

Tags: algorithm, date, overlapping

I have found similar problems around, but none considering a priority.

```
R : (------------|xxxxxxx|ooo|xx|----------------)   (---)

S1: (------------)              (----------------)   (---)
S2:      (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)   (xxxxxx)
S3:                   (ooooooo)           (oo)
```

Let's say I have 3 sources of date ranges, with names S1, S2 and S3 with priorities 1,2 and 3 respectively (1 being the highest) and a result R. I need the result to be non-overlapping date ranges where the highest priority takes precedence.

I have thought of a solution, but it's quite sequential. First I create a table ordered by ascending dates, descending priorities (in case of date collisions, highest priority goes first in the table) with their ID and action (open or close range):

```
ID  | Action | Priority | Date |
--------------------------------
S1a | Open   |    1     |  1   |
S2a | Open   |    2     |  2   |
S1a | Close  |    1     |  3   |
S3a | Open   |    3     |  4   |
S2a | Close  |    2     |  5   |
S2b | Open   |    2     |  6   |
S3a | Close  |    3     |  7   |
S1b | Open   |    1     |  8   |
S2b | Close  |    2     |  9   |
S3b | Open   |    3     |  10  |
S3b | Close  |    3     |  11  |
S1b | Close  |    1     |  12  |
S1c...
```

Then I start iterating this table and filling an ordered list and a result table:

So first row would be:

```
Order List:          Result:
ID | Priority |      ID | Action | Date  |  
S1a|    1     |      S1a|  Open  |  1    |
```

Second row, adds the opening date of S2a but doesn't write anything because bigger priority exists in the table:

```
Order List:          Result:
ID | Priority |      ID | Action | Date  |  
S1a|    1     |      S1a|  Open  |  1    |  
S2a|    2     |
```

Third row, closes S1a, writes the closing date and since S2a moves to the top of the list, it writes an opening date for S2a as well.

```
  Order List:          Result:
  ID | Priority |      ID | Action | Date  |  
x S1a|    1     |      S1a|  Open  |  1    |  
  S2a|    2     |      S1a|  Close |  3    |
                       S2a|  Open  |  3    |
```

I guess you can see where this is going... Lots of crosschecking etc. but in paper it seems to work. I can explain the algorithm a bit better if someone needs it, but I don't think it is hard to follow. If there is a higher priority in the ordered list, then is doesn't write anything. When the higher priority is removed, then the next biggest opens again.

Maybe anyone with a better, more concrete idea?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go about this would be to construct it in the opposite way, start by populating the table with the lowest priority and simply overwrite dates as you populate it with higher priority items. This keeps from having to create the order list and keep track of which items are opened waiting to be started.

> ***NOTE***: I should say up front that the following algorithm is almost assuredly less efficient (I didn't do the math but intuition
>   tells me it's less efficient). It's simply another way to approach the
>   problem.

It would be more beneficial in this way to group the open and close dates of each event. I'm going to refer to a beginning date to an ending date as an "event" for simplicity. So you start by adding each event of the lowest priority. Then you start looking through the data organized by priority, then by date. Like so:

```
ID  | Action | Priority | Date |
--------------------------------
S3a | Open   |    3     |  4   |
S3a | Close  |    3     |  7   |
S3b | Open   |    3     |  10  |
S3b | Close  |    3     |  11  |
S2a | Open   |    2     |  2   |
S2a | Close  |    2     |  5   |
S2b | Open   |    2     |  6   |
S2b | Close  |    2     |  9   |
S1a | Open   |    1     |  1   |
S1a | Close  |    1     |  3   |
S1b | Open   |    1     |  8   |
S1b | Close  |    1     |  12  |
-------------------------------
```

So simply go through the very lowest priority and add everything to the result:

**RESULT**:

```
ID  | Action | Priority | Date |
--------------------------------
S3a | Open   |    3     |  4   |
S3a | Close  |    3     |  7   |
S3b | Open   |    3     |  10  |
S3b | Close  |    3     |  11  |
```

This is where things get interesting, now you start looking at the events for the next highest priority. So we come across our first event `S2a`, what we do is we search for dates in the result that lie between `S2a Open` and `S2a Close`. If we think abstractly for a moment we'll get 3 different cases:

1. We find the beginning of an event.
2. We find the ending of an event.
3. We find both the beginning and the end of an event.

In the first case,  since the event's beginning will be pushed to the end of the higher priority event. That is set the contained events beginning to the `Close` of the current higher priority event.

In the second case, since the event's ending comes after the higher priority event's beginning it must end earlier. So we set the contained event's end to the `Open` of the current higher priority event.

In the final case, the entire event is contained inside the higher priority event and thus will be canceled altogether. That is delete both the beginning and ending.

So if we look at your example we have `S2a Open` = 2  and `S2a Close` = 5. The only date contained in that range is the `S3a Open`. So we'll change the date of `S3a Open` to the value of `S2a Close`, or 5. So now our result looks like:

**RESULT**:

```
ID  | Action | Priority | Date |
--------------------------------
S2a | Open   |    2     |  2   |
S2a | Close  |    2     |  5   |
S3a | Open   |    3     |  5   |
S3a | Close  |    3     |  7   |
S3b | Open   |    3     |  10  |
S3b | Close  |    3     |  11  |
```

It shouldn't be hard to extrapolate from this how the rest falls into place. (although let me know if you'd like more explanation.)

Depending on how the information is organized, and the data structures involved this may be less efficient than the way you've described. But I think this one is a little more intuitive in that you start by scheduling the lowest priority and then modify them to make time for the higher priority. I don't see a problem with the solution you gave and it does guarantee that you only look at each entry once (whereas mine could look at the item multiple times, or modify an item that is eventually clobbered by a later event).

I don't recommend my solution over yours but you didn't ask for efficiency, just a different way of looking at it.

Comment: Hey Don, thanks for your answer. Yeah, I just asked for alternatives because sometimes you get so much into your own solution, that you stop thinking any other way, and I was wandering if there is a different or known way to approach this problem. I will give it a thought. Cheers :)

Comment: I haven't come across anything, but to help point you in the right direction what you're defining is generally known as a "scheduling" problem. So searching for that might help you out (you didn't use that terminology anywhere in the question, so I'm assuming you didn't know it). Most everything I find doesn't have the rule set that the length of the events can change though, which gives you a quite unique problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote an algorithm that does this. I keep two arrays: one Result like yours and one array of intervals S (not of dates, but of what you termed ID's). Initially the array S is sorted on open '(' and Result is empty.

I also keep a kind of order list, but the difference with yours is that it is not sorted on Priority but on close ')'. This makes it quick to remove intervals from order list that no longer have to be considered because they 'lie in the past': you can keep an index an everything before that index is in the past.

The actual implementation does however not have a seperate order list, but re-uses S:

S[i] for i > index_1 is the input sorted on open '('

S[i] for i < index_1 is the order list sorted on close ')'

S[i] for i < index_2 'lie in the past'

So when a result entry is created and we need to get the next S, only the range index_1 -> index_2 needs to be searched (for the interval with highest priority).

lets see if I can recreate the first few iterations:

```
// initialize
S = [S1a,S2a,S3a,S2b,S1b,S3b,S1c]
R = []
index_1 = 0;
index_2 = 0;

// first result starts at smallest open
R1.start = S1a.open()
date = S1a.open() // 'current time'

// check if next entry in S ends the result R1
S[++index_1] = S2a: S2a.open() < S1a.close and S2a.Priority < S1a.Priority

// this does not end R1 -> keep S sorted, update index_2
S[index_1 - 1] = S1a, S[index_1] = S2a, S1a.close < S2a.close // -> OK! no swap needed
date = S2a.open()
S[index_2] = S1a: S1a.close() < date // -> OK! no update of index_2 needed

// check if next entry in S ends the result R1
S[++index_1] = S3a: S3.open() > S1a.close

// this ends R1 -> create it, update index_2
date = S1.close()
R1.close() = date
S[index_2] = S1a: S1a.close() = date // -> S1a is 'past'
index_2++ // update index_2
S[index_2] = S2a: S2a.close() < date // -> OK! no further update of index_2 needed

// find the next interval for R2
search S[i] index_2 <= i < index_1 and pick max priority
in this case index_2 = 1 and index_1 = 2 so we only need to check one entry (S2a)

R2.open = max( date, S2a.open() )

// continue...
```

sorry for any small mistake, but I hopefully conveyed the idea of the algorithm (it was not the intention to give all the details)

Not sure about performance, it depends on the type of data, I guess (if you have overlap between many intervals the range index_2 - index_1 is large and searching that range as well as sorting it on close ')' each time a new interval is added to the order list becomes expensive; if, however, you have only overlap between subsequent intervals index_2 - index_1 will be only 1 element, so both aforementioned actions are really cheap)

It is definitely less memory expensive, if that would be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Last week I wrote another algorithm; with improved worst case complexity. It has a priority queue (I used a heap); that is initially empty. And an array of intervals sorted on Open date.

```
A = [S1a,S2a,S3a,S2b,S1b,S3b,S1c]
H = []
```

We iterate over A (advance time); Each element of A will be enqueued into the queue. Since it's a priority queue, the root element H[0] contains the element with highest Priority. The root element will be dequeued once it closes.

You will see that the results are the root elements of the priority queue, with intervals corresponding with the "time" at which that element became the root (highest priority) until the time it was either dequeued from the queue (it closed) or "pushed down" by an new element enqueued into the queue (it was superseded by an interval of higher priority before closing).

More formally:

When we take the next element in A[i++] (advance time); we compare it with the current highest element H[0] in the priority queue; and check if A[i].Open > H[0].Close.

```
while( A[i].Open > H[0].Close )
{
    if( H[0].Close >= from ):
        We have a new result; R( S = H[0]; Open = from; Closed = H[0].Closed )
        Set from = H[0].Closed + 1;
    Dequeue H[0]
}
```

Once A[i].Open < H[0].Close, we enqueue A[i] into the priority queue. Two things can happen;

either A[i] is the interval with highest priority and becomes the new root. Then we have a new result; R( S = old root H[0]; Open = from; Closed = A[i].Open ); Set from = A[i].Open

Or A[i] "disappears" into the heap, H[0] does not change; and we continue.

Once we iterated through A; we continue dequeueing the queue, creating results if necessary; until the queue is empty.

For memory, you could implement this using a single array and only do swaps in this array; the first x indices are the heap; and the last y elements are the array A.

Run on your example:

//  i = 0: enqueue S1a

```
A = [S2a,S3a,S2b,S1b,S3b,S1c]
H = [S1a]
```

//  i = 1: enqueue S2a

```
A = [S3a,S2b,S1b,S3b,S1c]
H = [S1a,S2a]
```

//  i = 2: first result (----|; dequeue S1a; enqueue S3a

```
A = [S2b,S1b,S3b,S1c]
H = [S2a,S3a]
```

//  i = 3: second result |xx|; dequeue S2a (this makes S3a the root); enqueue S2b; third result |oo| (since S2b drives S3a from the root position)

```
A = [S1b,S3b,S1c]
H = [S2b,S3a]
```

// i = 4; enqueue S1b; fourth result |xx|

```
A = [S3b,S1c]
H = [S1b,S3a,S2b]
```

// i = 5; enqueue S3b

```
A = [S1c]
H = [S1b,S3a,S2b,S3b]
```

// i = 6; fifth result |----); dequeue S1b, dequeue S3a, S2b and S3b without creating results; enqueue S1c

```
A = []
H = [S1c]
```

// sixth result (--); dequeue S1c; stop

Answer (score 0):

Bartel algo using a priority queue is quite good - 
The algo breaks on disjoint intervals because:

```
    while( A[i].Open > H[0].Close )
{
    if( H[0].Close >= from ):
        We have a new result; R( S = H[0]; Open = from; Closed = H[0].Closed )
        Set from = H[0].Closed + 1;
    Dequeue H[0]
}
```

which is the case of non overlapping intervals should actually be:

```
while( A[i].Open > H[0].Close )
{
    if( H[0].Close >= from ):
        We have a new result; R( S = H[0]; Open = from; Closed = H[0].Closed )
        Set from = A[i].from;
    Dequeue H[0]
}
```

that is the new from is coming from the next interval

Comment: Consider the following intervals ([interval], prio): ([1,4],0), ([2,3],1), ([5,6],0). The desired result: { [1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [5,6] }; I think your suggestion would go wrong on the [3,4] in the result. What you need, I think, is something in the outer loop (the one that sets i = i + 1) that, after Enqueue(A[i]), sets from = MAX(from, H[0].Open); or alternatively if(H[0]==A[i]) from = A[i].Open; I should check my original code to make sure.